# Why colors are different in Minecraft and web browser

Tags: java, html, css, colors, minecraft

I want to create a page(on react if it matters) where I can choose a color and see how it will look in Minecraft(using similar font, background color of a chat and shadow) but I was surprised I choose same color with hex in my code and Minecraft
Like: "color: #2CF1DE" in web and "&#2CF1DE" in Minecraft and I see a bit different colors.
I was researching a bit and found out that there are different color spaces(not sure about browser and minecraft difference), is that a reason why I see different colors? Or maybe there are some color filters in the game..
Can I make the color in the browser the same as in the game?

I attached a screenshot:

[image]

Web browser on the left side and Minecraft on the right
nickname and "Test message" colors should be the same(as I thought)

p.s. Obviously color in minecraft is 'wrong' cause I check it witch color picker on image and #2CF1DE(I entered &#2CF1DE) turns to #FF404C

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. Just use the correct text shadow color.

Comment: No, it's not I said "Obviously color in minecraft is 'wrong' cause I check it with color picker on image and #2CF1DE(I entered &#2CF1DE) turns to #FF404C"